Upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04 without a snap install
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on a WSLv1 system, which does not support snap:
$ snap list
Interacting with snapd is not yet supported on Windows Subsystem for Linux 1.
This command has been left available for documentation purposes only.

Doing sudo do-release-upgrade breaks with:
sudo do-release-upgrade

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/noble", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2642, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2447, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1438, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 102, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 127, in noblePostInitialUpdate
    self._test_and_fail_on_tpm_fde()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-uqmd8iby/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 1898, in _test_and_fail_on_tpm_fde
    snap_list = subprocess.check_output(['snap', 'list'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['snap', 'list']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

It is only fair because snap list errors out. Is it possible to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 by somehow disabling any snap interaction and sidetracking its attempt to do snap list?
Thanks!

Okay, it appears that this is a bug/problem in the DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py script. Because this script gets only created in a temporary, randomly-named directory when sudo do-release-upgrade is run, it is hard to modify this script. But if we manage to stroke Ctrl+Z immediately after extraction of noble.tar.gz, we can modify the script and then stroke fg. The required modification: comment-out the call of self._test_and_fail_on_tpm_fde().
After this modification, my release process continued as it should. If anyone knows, how to modify this script without pressing Ctrl+Z at the right time - please let me know and comment, I'll include these comments in this note.
References:

https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues/493
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11982

